# How to add a Widget to another Widget in DOJO?

Tags: javascript, dojo

When User click a button, I need to add a WidgetB to WidgetA (I suppose using WidgetA containerNode ).

I have tried in the button event listener the following but with no success:

```
   var item = registry.byId('wA');
   item.containerNode.innerHTML = '<span id="wB" data-dojo-type="WidgetB"></span>'
   parser.instantiate(['wB']);
```

I would need a working example, thanks.

http://jsbin.com/johixagebo/1/

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
        require([
            "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/parser", "dojo/ready",
            "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/registry"
        ], function (declare, parser, ready, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, lang, registry) {
            var propA = {
                templateString: "<div>" +
                    "<div>WidgetA: <span data-dojo-attach-point='customNode'></span></div>" +
                    '<div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"></div>' +
                    "</div>",
                custom: "CUSTOM DEFAULT",
                _setCustomAttr: function (value) {
                    this.custom = value;
                    this.customNode.innerHTML = value;
                }
            };
            var propB = {
                templateString: "<div>" +
                    "<div>WidgetB: <span data-dojo-attach-point='customNode'></span></div>" +
                    "</div>",
                custom: "CUSTOM DEFAULT",
                _setCustomAttr: function (value) {
                    this.custom = value;
                    this.customNode.innerHTML = value;
                }
            };
            declare("WidgetA", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], propA);
            //declare("WidgetB", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], propA);


            ready(function () {
                parser.parse();
                registry.byId("wA").set("custom", 'XYZ');
                document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    var item = registry.byId('wA');
                    item.containerNode.innerHTML = '<span id="wB" data-dojo-type="WidgetB"></span>'
                    parser.instantiate(['wB']);
                }.bind(this));
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <span id="wA" data-dojo-type="WidgetA"></span>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="add child B to A">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution using the following code:

using:

- parser.instantiate() http://jsbin.com/vetizefehe/1/
- parser.parser() http://jsbin.com/rupejizizi/1/

Basically I modify the DOM element `containerNode` with a new HTML containing `dojo-type` data attribute to my custom widget (WigetB).

After I allow DOJO parsing selectively based on the new added Widget using [parse.initiate()](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/parser.html#id17) or parser.parser() .

I am still very interested to know if there is a better way to achieve the same result, as I am not sure if selective parsing is the best option.

Notes:

parser.parser() 
Works great also if the HTML contains several nested level of widgets.
parser.initiate() 
Works only for 1 level nesting.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <style>
        #wA {
            top: 0;
            background-color: lightblue;
        }

        #wB {
            top: 100px;
            background-color: lightcoral;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        require([
            "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/parser", "dojo/ready",
            "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/registry"
        ], function (declare, parser, ready, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, lang, registry) {
            var propA = {
                templateString: "<div>" +
                    "<div><span data-dojo-attach-point='customNode'></span></div>" +
                    '<div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"></div>' +
                    "</div>",
                custom: "CUSTOM DEFAULT",
                _setCustomAttr: function (value) {
                    this.custom = value;
                    this.customNode.innerHTML = value;
                }
            };
            var propB = {
                templateString: "<div>" +
                    "<div><span data-dojo-attach-point='customNode'></span></div>" +
                    "</div>",
                custom: "CUSTOM DEFAULT",
                _setCustomAttr: function (value) {
                    this.custom = value;
                    this.customNode.innerHTML = value;
                }
            };
            declare("WidgetA", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], propA);
            declare("WidgetB", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], propA);


            ready(function () {
                parser.parse();
                registry.byId("wA").set("custom", 'XYZ');
                document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    var item = registry.byId('wA');
                    item.containerNode.innerHTML = '<span id="wB" data-dojo-type="WidgetB"></span>'
                    parser.instantiate([dojo.byId("wB")]);

                    console.log(registry.byId('wA'));
                    console.log(registry.byId('wB'));

                }.bind(this));
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <span id="wA" data-dojo-type="WidgetA"></span>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="add child B to A">
</body>

</html>
```

---